# How can I call bootstrap 5 modals with Javascript without including jQuery in the scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I know there are similar questions about this error, but I would like to find a solution without including jquery to my scripts. I'm getting an error trying to call bootstrap 5 modals with JS. I think this may be related to including jquery in the scripts, but I when I tried that some other parts of my code broke. So I was trying to do the simplest example from the bootstrap 5 documentation and I get the same error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I would appreciate any help on this.

The following is a plane html with the whole code, all taken from getbootstrap.com. This includes the starter template plus the example in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
</script>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use bootstrap modals without calling jquery

If you want you can do this with html and pure js

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='openModal()'>
   Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-modal="true"
role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="closeModal()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show" id="backdrop" style="display: none;"></div>

function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById("exampleModal").style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById("exampleModal").classList.add("show")
}
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("exampleModal").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("exampleModal").classList.remove("show")
}
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('exampleModal');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
      closeModal()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did something along those lines to solve and continue, but I still think there should be another way. Bootstrap 5 doesn't use jQuery, I haven't researched deep into this, but modals do work without calling jQuery in v5, but in this case, as I was including the jQuery call it didn't work.